# Unable to bind observablecollection to View using Knockout

Tags: jquery, json, html, wcf, knockout.js

My View Model is :

```
function MyInfo(data) {
        this.line = ko.observable(data);

    }
function MyViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.Plines = ko.observableArray([]);

            $.getJSON("URL",
            function (allData) {
                 var mappedData = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new MyInfo(item) });
            self.Plines = mappedData;
            });
            alert(self.Plines);

        }

        ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

And View does just have a Select.

```
<select data-bind="options: Plines,  optionsText: ''"></select>
```

The JSON response I have is:

```
["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4","Item5"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `self.Plines = allData;` to `self.Plines(allData);`

Also, change:

```
<select data-bind="options: Plines,  optionsText: ''"></select>
```

to

```
<select data-bind="options: Plines,  optionsText: 'line'"></select>
```

[here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uNLu3/1/)

Comment: Tried that , even then it shows the Callback in alert not the actual data

Comment: @Simsons, I missed that optionText wasn't set either.